# "Le toilette" au masculin - usage régional ?

Tags: genre, régionalismes

En regardant l'émission *Chasseurs d'appart'*, j'ai été surpris d'entendre plusieurs personnes (visiblement dont la langue maternelle était bien le français) utiliser le mot "toilette" au masculin pour désigner le pot en email lui-même (et non la pièce).

Ex:

> le toilette est mal placé, il est trop près de la porte.

Cette émission était tournée dans la région de Besançon. Est-ce un régionalisme de cette région ? Est-ce utilisé dans d'autres parties de France ou Suisse (voire du Québec) ? Pour ma part, je ne pense jamais avoir entendu "le toilette" dans ma Belgique natale.

Answer (score 1):

Je pense que c'est juste un abus de langage pour parler de 'la cuvette des toilettes'. C'est peut-être un régionalisme, en tout cas je le comprends sans sourciller (je suis aussi frontalier de la Suisse).

Answer (score 1):

En Belgique, j'ai toujours entendu l'expression *aller **à la** toilette* alors qu'en France, c'est toujours *aller **aux** toilettes* (aux WC, aux cabinets, aux "ouatères", aux chiottes...)

La cuvette elle-même est rarement appelée *toilette*, mais quand c'est le cas, on rencontre en effet parfois le masculin. Il s'explique peut-être par « **le** cabinet de toilette », « **le** siège des toilettes » ou comme moyen de le distinguer de « **la** toilette » signifiant l'action de se laver ou parfois un ensemble de vêtements.

Ce masculin n'a pas l'air d'être limité à la Franche-Comté. On en trouve quelques exemples sur Internet comme celui-ci :

Ex:  [Étapes d'installation d'un toilette sur pied](https://www.batinea.com/comment-fixer-wc-au-sol-sans-percer)

Comment: C'était sans doute vrai avant, je me rappelle d'une blague: "En France, on dit aller aux toilettes parce qu'il faut toujours en faire plusieurs pour en trouver une propre". Mais j'ai l'impression que le pluriel s'impose peu à peu. Pour désigner la cuvette, on emploie aussi parfois tout simplement "le pot",

Comment: Au Québec on emploie aussi le « bol » pour cuvette. Ouais le singulier c'est la marque de la Suisse/Belgique/Québec. Mais le toilette au masculin est absolument inusité pour moi. Perso. je ne l'ai jamais entendu de ma vie et je ne connais pas de mot en -ette au masculin il me semble.

Comment: @AmandeAdorable Il y a indiscutablement *le squelette*, sinon, plus proche de ce *toilette*, il y a *le trompette* (celui qui joue de la trompette) et beaucoup de noms composés (*le casse-noisette, le fume-cigarette*, etc.)